# how to allow delay in looped http request but also use Promise.all to detect when requests are done

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

Hi I am trying to allow 50ms before next http request is made to the server but also would like to implement some function when all the request have been made.

I made an example to illustrate what I would like to do.

So below is my example express api

```
app.get('/morans/test', (req, res) => {
    console.log(`start test request`);
    let targetUrl = `http://-domain-/solr/genea_expression/smplGeoclust?q=text:"GO:0003674"&stats.facet=geohash_3&rows=10320`;
    let i = 0;
    let promises = [];

    console.log(`making request ${i}`);


    for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
        setTimeout(
            () => {
                let testReq = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    http.get(targetUrl, (result) => {
                        result.on('data', (chunk) => {
                            console.log(`working ${i}`);
                        }).on('end', () => {
                            console.log(`ending ${i}`);
                        }).on('error', (err) => {
                            console.log(`this is error message ${err}`);
                        })
                    })
                });

                promises.push(testReq);
            }, 50 * i
        )
    }
    Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
        console.log(`done`);
    });
});
```

The delay works fine; however, `Promise.all(promises)...` is getting a premature trigger (`console.log('done')` triggers as soon as first request is made). It works fine when there is no timeout so I am thinking that the `setTimeout` is not allowing enough time for promise to be pushed to `promises` array. How can I write a code so that http request is made in every 50ms but also know when all the requests are successfully returned?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `Promise.all` at a time your `promises` array is empty, since none of the time outs has expired yet.

You could move that `Promise.all` call inside your timeout callback, right after the `push`, and check the length of that array:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    setTimeout(
        () => {
            // ...etc ... etc
            promises.push(testReq);
            if (promises.length == 200) { // <---- add this block
                Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                    console.log(`done`);
                });
            } 
        }, 50 * i
    )
}
```

Also make sure you call `resolve()` within your `new Promise` callback, otherwise your promises will stay pending:

```
                    .on('end', () => {
                        console.log(`ending ${i}`);
                        resolve();
                    })
```

See the [documentation on `http.get`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback) to see how to actually get the response data... It would make sense to call `resolve` with that data as argument.

Comment: Thank you! works like a charm. Also thanks for great catch on `resolve()`. I had it on my actual api but forgot to put it in the test api. Thanks so much for help!